# how to Access monitor information from the Video RAM and display it on GUI using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, pci-e

I am using Xilinx Spartans SP605 board to access pciexpress through PCI bus. For that i am using JUNGO tool( Windriver) for generating the drivers for the device used and then accessing the PCIexpress card by performing read and write operation using C# sample generated code by JUNGO.

Now, along with the read write operations performed, i want to send video signal. For example, I need to send the video information from the VIDEO RAM or graphics card that is send to the monitor for displaying. I need to take all the video information give to the PCIexpress card and display all the information on the GUI. Like a small monitor on the GUI, it should act same as a monitor and do whatever a monitor does like if i am clicking on start button, then the same action need to be performed on the GUI.
Like a DUAL monitor on a same screen.

Please help me with the c# program on how to access monitor information.

looking for a positive reply.

Comment: This is way too broad, what you (seem to be) asking for is for us to design a program for you. That isn't what this site is about.

Comment: Its an interesting question. however, you ask a lot of total strangers. i mean whats in it for me? Seriously though, waaay too broad. Additionally, not attempt at working it out